# Find sequences in list of ranges

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy

I have a random length list that contains ranges info:

```
list = [
 [[7, 12], [6, 12], [38, 44], [25, 30], [25, 29]], 
 [[0, 5], [1, 5], [2, 5], [12, 16], [13, 16], [20, 23], [29, 33], [30, 33]], 
 [[5, 7], [6, 8], [7, 9], [8, 10], [9, 11], [10, 12], [16, 18], [17, 19], [18, 20], [23, 25], [24, 26], [25, 27], [26, 28], [27, 29], [33, 35], [34, 36], [35, 37], [36, 38], [37, 39], [38, 40], [39, 41], [40, 42], [41, 43], [42, 44]]
]
```

For example, first element `[[7, 12], [6, 12], [38, 44], [25, 30]]` contains 4 ranges 7-12, 6-12, 38-44 and 25-30 etc.

I need to find the all possible chains (a chain is an array of consecutive ranges where ending of first range == beginning of next range) of length given list length, given that I could and should take only one range from each row in the exact order of rows.

So, for this example list:
The chains would be 
`[[6, 12], [12, 16], [16, 18]]`, 
`[[7, 12], [12, 16], [16, 18]]`, 
`[[25, 30], [30, 33], [33, 35]]` 
and `[[25, 29], [29, 33], [33, 35]]`

Right now I am stuck on working with more than three length list, could not come up with recursive solution.

Comment: It seems to me the first step would be to flatten the lists into one list.

Comment: You say that you're stuck but you haven't shared your current code. Please post what you've got so far.

Comment: @josh I don't think the lists can be flattened because of the "should take only one range from each row in the exact order of rows".

Comment: @TomDalton Ah, I didn't see that condition there. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `[[25, 30], [29, 33], [33, 35]]` here ending of `[25,30]` does not equal beginning of `[29,33]`

Comment: If you only have three "rows", then your longest chain can only be of length 3, correct?

Comment: It says "all possible chains of length given list length", so all chains are exactly of length 3.

Comment: Also, it is strongly advised against using a [builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) name as an identifier name (`list`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to iterate over all possible chains (all combinations of 1 range from each "row"),

then filter them by a simple function that checks if a specific chain is legal.

try this:

```py
from itertools import product

def check_chain(chain):
    prev_end = chain[0][1]
    for start, end in chain[1:]:
        if start != prev_end:
            return False
        prev_end = end
    return True

all_candidate_chains = product(*list)

result = [[*chain] for chain in all_candidate_chains if check_chain(chain)]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[[7, 12], [12, 16], [16, 18]], [[6, 12], [12, 16], [16, 18]], [[25, 30], [30, 33], [33, 35]]]
```

EDIT:

can also use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to replace `check_chain` with a 1-liner:

```py
from itertools import product
result = [[*chain] for chain in product(*list) if all(end1 == start2 for (_, end1), (start2, _) in zip(chain, chain[1:]))]
print(result)
```

Comment: If anyone is curious: Time complexity here is `O(N x M^N)`, if there are `N` rows and `M` columns.

Comment: Yeah I'd agree this will be inefficient for large inputs compared to a 'traditional' depth first search with immediate pruning.

Comment: yup, that's a totally brute force approach. sometimes it's fine to just let the nested loops go brrrrrrrrrrrrrr..... :P  https://ericlippert.com/2020/03/27/new-grad-vs-senior-dev/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without looking at all the permutation. Start at with the last item and make a dictionary where the keys are the first value in the dictionary. Then work backward through the list and lookup the previous key based on the second value of the tuple adding to the array as you go:

In the end you'll have a dictionary keyed to the first value in the tuples of the first list. You can just flatten the values at this point.

Here I added one more pair `[12,9]` to the middle list so I could see it work with branching paths:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

l = [
 [[7, 12], [6, 12], [38, 44], [25, 30]], 
 [[0, 5], [1, 5], [2, 5], [12, 16], [12, 9],[13, 16], [20, 23], [29, 33], [30, 33]], 
 [[5, 7], [6, 8], [7, 9], [8, 10], [9, 11], [10, 12], [16, 18], [17, 19], [18, 20], [23, 25], [24, 26], [25, 27], [26, 28], [27, 29], [33, 35], [34, 36], [35, 37], [36, 38], [37, 39], [38, 40], [39, 41], [40, 42], [41, 43], [42, 44]]
]


d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in l[-1]:
    d[k].append([[k,v]])

for sub in reversed(l[:-1]):
    ds = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in sub:
        if v in d:
            ds[k].extend([[k,v], *v2] for v2 in d[v] )
    d = ds

list(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
```

Output:

```
[[[7, 12], [12, 16], [16, 18]],
 [[7, 12], [12, 9], [9, 11]],
 [[6, 12], [12, 16], [16, 18]],
 [[6, 12], [12, 9], [9, 11]],
 [[25, 30], [30, 33], [33, 35]]]
```